# SSIS Execute SQL Error: " "

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am getting an error when trying to Execute an SQL file with an **Execute SQL Task** in **SSIS** (2012).

> Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "" failed with the following
>   error: "".

I am trying to automate a process to import a file from **TestRail** that drops and recreates tables and then fills them with data.

I can open the file in **SQL Server Management Studio**. I do get an **Inconsistent Line Endings** warning when I open the file but it works when I click Yes or No to Normalizing them). It actually worked the first time I created the process but the file was much smaller as we didn't have much data at the time.

Any ideas as to why a query might fail in **SSIS** but run in **SSMS**? I'm thinking it might be some funky syntax that SSMS figures out but SSIS can't.

Here's the whole error message:

> SSIS package "\valinor.k-net.com\Users\bs\documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\TFS\Data Analysts\SSIS PACKAGES\SSIS
>   PACKAGES\TestRailRefresh.dtsx" starting. Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute
>   SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "" failed with the
>   following error: "". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the
>   query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not established correctly. Task failed:
>   Execute SQL Task Warning: 0x80019002 at TestRailRefresh: SSIS Warning
>   Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded,
>   but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1);
>   resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
>   the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
>   MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. SSIS package
>   "\valinor.k-net.com\Users\bs\documents\Visual Studio 2012\TFS\Data
>   Analysts\SSIS PACKAGES\SSIS PACKAGES\TestRailRefresh.dtsx" finished:
>   Failure. The program '[146976] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you post the entire error stack?

Comment: @matt-a, I added the entire error message - though the rest of the message seems pretty generic.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding and/or cleaning the solution?  Sometimes that error is a meta data issue.

Comment: @matt-a - I tried recreating from scratch but no dice. I broke it up into pieces and found the part that it errors on has some Java. SSIS does add some escape characters to it but it runs in SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting many hours on this, it turns out this is expected stupid behavior by SSIS. Apparently, Microsoft thinks that using a **$(** is only for internal variables and would **NEVER** be used by someone in an actual query.

This would run is SSMS but fail in SSIS:

```
SELECT 'Total: $(1200).'
```

I fixed the issue by using REPLACE to add a space between the characters - **$ (**.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

Screw you, Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Users have reported that the maximum size of the submitted task is 32K. I suspect the string you are submitting is longer then that. Perhaps your inserts can be broken up into multiple Execute tasks.

Comment: Yes - it's currently almost 4 meg of SQL - though it was still 700k when I started. I have broken it up into smaller pieces and have found two of the 200ish queries to error with the same "" message. There's some java in a field and SSIS is escaping some of it ( \" ). Though when I copy the query that fails from my variable and run it in SSMS, it runs without issue. :(